# c kill other child processes once answer is found

Tags: c, process, fork

Hello I am trying to write some code in c that splits a job into 3 processes, each looking for an answer in a third of the range of answers (ie. process a looks between 1 and 10, process b looks between 10 and 20, and process c looks between 20 and 30). I am using a simple for loop for this, then forking running code on the children processes. I would like to, upon the finding of the correct answer, terminate all the other child processes (which will never find the right answer, so their running is superfluous). Using sigkill I can kill the child and the parent, but not the siblings, so to speak. How would this best be accomplished?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){ //this is the child process just forked
        char* answer = myFunction(domain[i]);
        if (answer != NULL){
            printf("answer: %s\n"); 
            //now terminate all other child processes, seeing as their answer was not in their domain
        }
        break;
        }else{
            //do nothing as this is the parent process
        }
    }
}

//handle results
```

Comment: Either kill the process group, or have the parent send a signal to all children when it catches a signal.

Comment: Obviously, if the parent is going to be catching the signal, you will not want to use SIGKILL.

Comment: How would I have the parent send a signal to all the children?

Comment: You can use sockets or named pipes to transfer data between processes.

Comment: Have the parent keep track of the pid of each child and open a pipe to each child.  When one child finds the result, it send it back though the pipe to the parent.  The parent should wait for data on each of the pipes.  When one of them returns something, the parent can then kill off the children.

Comment: @dbush this looks like a good solution I don't know about pipes but I'll read up 

Comment: The easiest solution is to first fork *one* child process, have that process call `setsid()` to become a process group leader, then have the child processes of that process group leader do the actual processing and kill the entire process group after `my_function()`. The first child process to get there will kill the entire group. No extra interprocess communication is necessary.